# Proving that $f'$ is measurable on $\mathbb R$ if$f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, functional-analysis, measure-theory, continuity

Since $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$ it is then continuous on $\mathbb R$,making $f$ measurable. (this we proved in class-that continuous functions are measurable).
I tried to use this to prove the measurability of $f'(x)$.

$$f'(x_0)=\lim_{x\to x_0} \frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}$$

What is inside the limit is measurable because it is an algebraic expression on measurable functions. What is left to prove is proving that the limit of this measurable function is measurable. Is it possible to go about this in this manner?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, this is the correct direction.

Since $f$ is differentiable, for every $x \in \mathbb{R}$ we have
$$f'(x) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x + h) - f(x)}{h}.$$

Now, we define the translation $f_h (x) = f(x + h)$. Since $f_h$ is continuous, it is measurable. Now, you have
$$\frac{f_h - f}{h} \to f'$$
pointwise everywhere. As the pointwise limit of measurable functions is measurable, you get the measurability of $f'$.

Comment: I am not sure about this, doesnt pointwise limit of measurable functions mean that we take a sequence of $f_n(x)$ measurable functions, then $\lim_{n\to \infty} f_n$ is measurable. I don't see that here.

Comment: Just take a sequence of $h$'s, e.g. consider $(f_{1/n} - f)/(1/n)$ for $n \in \mathbb{N}$. Since $f$ is differentiable, the exact sequence does not matter.

Comment: why it is pointwise everywhere ?

Comment: Because the derivative exists at all $x$.