# Why the convergence is pointwise in this question and why the translation is continuous?

Tags: measure-theory, continuity, proof-writing, sequence-of-function, pointwise-convergence

I was reading this question here [Proving that $f'$ is measurable on $\mathbb R$ if$f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb R$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556374/proving-that-f-is-measurable-on-mathbb-r-iff-is-differentiable-on-math).

**But I did not understand the following points in the solution:**

1- why the translation $f_{h}(x)= f(x + h)$ continuous? could anyone give me a rigorous proof for this, please?

2- Why the convergence is pointwise everywhere here: " Now, you have
$$\frac{f_h - f}{h} \to f'$$
pointwise everywhere"? could anyone give me a rigorous proof for this, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$f'(x) =\lim_{n \to \infty} f_n(x)$ where $f_n(x)=\frac {f(x+\frac 1 n)-f(x)} {1/n}$. So it is enough to check that each $f_n$ is measurable. But $f_n$ is continuous and that finishes the proof.

1) If $x_k \to x$ then $x_k+\frac 1 n \to x+\frac 1 n$ so $f(x_k+\frac 1 n) \to f(x+\frac 1 n)$  in view of the fact that any differentiable function is continuous.

2) This is by definition of derivative.

Comment: which proof that is finished? the proof of the question is already mentioned in the link but it lacks the following details I am asking about.

Comment: @hopefully I have edited my answer.

Comment: you mean the definition of the derivative say that it is a pointwise convergence everywhere?

Comment: Yes, at each point $x$ apply the definition of derivative. @hopefully

Answer (score 1):

By definition,
$$f'(x)=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}=\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{f_h(x)-f(x)}{h}$$
And for 2, just check the definition of pointwise convergence.

Comment: I have edited my first question. Could please show me the details of 1 & 2?

Comment: @hopefully $f$ is differentiable on $\mathbb{R}$, hence continuous. So it's continuous at $x+h$ as well, because $x+h\in\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @hopefully for the second one, pick your favorite null-sequence, which is non-zero, for example $h_n = 1/n$. Note that \frac{f(x+1/n)-f(x)}{1/n}\to f'(x)$, because $f$ is differentiable at $x$.

Comment: what do you mean by $null-sequence$ and why should I pick it null?

Comment: @hopefully a sequence is a null-sequence if it's limit is zero. And you should pick one because you have $h\to 0$ in the definition of derivative.